# Custom or override join in Sequelize.js

Tags: javascript, sql-server, database, sequelize.js

I need to create a custom join condition using [Sequelize.js](http://sequelizejs.com) with MSSQL. Specifically, I need to join `TableB` based on a `COALESCE` value from columns in `TableA` and `TableB` and end up with a join condition like this:

```sql
LEFT OUTER JOIN [TableB]
    ON [TableB].[ColumnB] = COALESCE (
        [TableC].[ColumnC],
        [TableA].[ColumnA]
    )
```

I'd settle for an `OR` clause in my join:

```sql
LEFT OUTER JOIN [TableB]
    ON [TableB].[ColumnB] = [TableA].[ColumnA]
    OR [TableB].[ColumnB] = [TableC].[ColumnC]
```

I [read](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39774664/2345211) that you can achieve behaviour like this by including `required: false` in your scope definition. As you can see, I've plastered my scope with it attempting to get this to work.

The best I could get is this (note the `AND` clause):

```sql
LEFT OUTER JOIN [TableB]
    ON [TableB].[ColumnB] = [TableA].[ColumnA]
    AND [TableB].[ColumnB] = COALESCE (
        [TableC].[ColumnC],
        [TableA].[ColumnA]
    )
```

If I were using MySQL, I think I could simply use the `COALESCE` value from the `SELECT` in the `JOIN` and be good to go but in my prior research read that it was required to recalculate the value.

I've included a stripped down model definition for `TableA`:

```
export default (sequelize, DataTypes) => sequelize.define('TableA',
    {
        // Attributes omitted..
    },
    {
        classMethods: {
            associate ({
                TableB,
                TableC
            }) {
                this.belongsTo(TableB, {
                    foreignKey: 'ColumnA',
                    targetKey: 'ColumnB'
                });

                this.belongsTo(TableC, {
                    foreignKey: 'ColumnA',
                    targetKey: 'ColumnC'
                });
            },
            attachScope ({
                TableB,
                TableC
            }) {
                this.addScope('defaultScope', {
                    attributes: [
                        ...Object.keys(this.attributes),
                        [
                            sequelize.fn(
                                'COALESCE',
                                sequelize.col('[TableC].[ColumnC]'),
                                sequelize.col('[TableA].[ColumnA]')
                            ),
                            'ColumnA'
                        ]
                    ],
                    include: [
                        {
                            model: TableB,
                            where: {
                                ColumnB: sequelize.fn(
                                    'COALESCE',
                                    sequelize.col('[TableC].[ColumnC]'),
                                    sequelize.col('[TableA].[ColumnA]')
                                )
                            },
                            required: false
                        },
                        {
                            model: TableC,
                            required: false
                        }
                    ],
                    required: false
                }, { override: true });
            }
        }
    }
);
```

Any assistance would be greatly appreciated, and if any additional information is required please let me know.

*Note: I'm working with a legacy database and unfortunately cannot change the data structure.*

Answer (score 0):

Hi I had the same issue and finally I solved using a SQL pure query.

Example:

```
const query = `SELECT s.*, us.UserId \
                FROM UserSections AS us \
                RIGHT JOIN Sections AS s ON (s.id = us.SectionId) \
                WHERE s.parentId = ${sectionId}`;

return db.query(query, { type: db.QueryTypes.SELECT });
```

The problem is that this function will return a IMyType instead of IMyTypeInstance

Can it works for you??

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but I've got a few layers of associations which precludes me from simply using a raw query. I wish I could, though!